# Python Pynput hotkey issue involving easygui window

Tags: python

I wrote some code to help to copy and paste multiple lines in a program that doesn't allow you to copy and paste multiple rows nicely like excel does. I've tried writing this tool in AHK but something about AHK doesn't seem to play nice with the program in question (RSLogix studio 5000, AHK always misses lines when copy and pasting). This python code works nicely and doesn't miss lines when copying or pasting, but I've encountered a new issue. Despite what I've set the hotkeys to (ctrl 1 brings up a window asking how many lines you'd like to copy or paste, ctrl 2 copies that many lines, ctrl 3 pastes that many lines) pressing ctrl always brings up the input window. If I remove the input window and hardcode the value for "lines" then everything works as expected. Something about this window is making the program act strangely. Does anyone have any ideas?

thanks in advance for your time:)

```
import pyautogui
import easygui
import keyboard
import pyperclip
import time

from pynput.keyboard import HotKey, Key, KeyCode, Listener
from pynput import keyboard
copy_list=[]
lines = 0

def function_1():
    global lines
    lines = easygui.integerbox("Enter number of lines to copy")
    print(lines)
def function_2():
    global lines
    copy_list.clear()
    for x in range(int(lines)):
        pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c') 
        clp=pyperclip.paste()
        pyperclip.copy("")
        copy_list.append(clp)
        pyautogui.press('down') 
    print(copy_list)
    
def function_3():
    global lines
    for x in range(int(lines)): 
        pyperclip.copy(copy_list[x])
        pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')  
        pyautogui.press('enter',presses=3,interval=0.05)

with keyboard.GlobalHotKeys({
        '<ctrl>+1': function_1,
        '<ctrl>+2': function_2,
        '<ctrl>+3': function_3}) as h:
    h.join()
```